# Animating the merging of multiple video strips

Tags: video-sequence-editor, masking

I'm trying to achieve the merging of multiple video strips like in the following [15 sec in, to 16 sec in - caravan to boat clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qO1kiOiMCNg#t=15). I think the clip has been animated with a vertical strip.

- Could this animated area be achieved with masks in Blender?
- If so, how would I go about achieving an animated visible video area, over another video?

Comment: It ***can*** be done in blender... whether you will appear sane at the other end is questionable :P. After effects/final cut pro would be much better for this.

Comment: unfortunately I don't have after effects/final cut pro. How can it be done in Blender?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a couple ways, but I would use [masks](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.64/Mask_Editor):

[image]

1. With a strip selected, add a mask modifier in the properties region (<kbd>N</kbd>) by pressing *Add strip modifier > Mask*. I also like to set the alpha blending to *alpha over*:

   [image]

   You can either use another strip to control the selected strip's alpha channel. You could use a scene strip to generate such a map based on the render output of a scene, or you could use an animated [mask](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.64/Mask_Editor).
2. To create a mask, use the *UV/image editor* with the mode set to *mask*. Press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and select the type of mask to create.
3. To animate it, transform it with <kbd>G</kbd> (translate) <kbd>S</kbd> (scale) and <kbd>R</kbd> (rotate). Insert keyframes with <kbd>I</kbd>.

   To move the keyframes around/delete them, you can use the dopesheet in *mask mode*:

   [image]

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be any way to get the image editor to update in realtime at the moment, so you'll have to manually refresh it by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>. For that to work, the viewed image must be set to *Render result*.

**[Result:](http://gfycat.com/DangerousRegularHydatidtapeworm)**

[image]

Comment: I've figured out how to animate the masks in the **movie editor**, but is there a way to see the key frames in the graph editor? I'm struggling to accurately move the keyframes around and sync them to my video strips. Is there a tutorial any-ware on how to accurately position key frames in the movie clip editor?

Comment: In the VSE you can Add->Mask->MaskName - the list of masks are those created in the movie editor.

Comment: In the UV image editor you can keyframe masks by pressing I. See the wiki for more info: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.64/Mask_Editor. I don't have time to atm, but I'll update my answer with more detail..

Comment: Good question, great answer

Comment: good answer and you've trumped my up coming tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

As well as keyframing masks you can get a lot of control by making your own animated video strip and using it as a mask strip. CGCookie has a [archived tutorial](https://cgcookie.com/archive/vse-custom-mask-transitions/) that covers making and using the mask video. The only other tutorial I know of is [by David McSween](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qK-k2N2Vxig), he uses a single greyscale image and animates the brightness and contrast to get the transition.

The basics of creating an animated video to use as a mask is to create a video that defines the transition, black shows the old strip, white shows the new strip with levels of grey a mixture of the two. You can easily imagine using blender to create a simple animation of shapes for this, add this transition video as a strip in the VSE and then add a mask modifier and select the transition strip.