# Animating masks to create multiple wipes

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video, transparency, masking

So... I'm making yet another video. And I want to recreate this effect:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hDiJ17Xgaw8 (its in the first 15 seconds)
So I have kinda the general idea of how to do this, which may be complete reduntant.
My thought is to have 2 planes scaled out on the x axis and y axis, and animate their location, than to put the scene into VSE or MCE, and have video #1 be in the top left, video #2 in the top right, and so on. And I think if I could somehow parent a mask to an empty that is parented to the plane, that would work.
  So my question is how do I parent a mask point to an object?
Any help GREATLY appreciated!!!

EDIT: Ok, so I'm realizing that parenting masks to an object isn't really going to work. I'm going to use objects in the 3D scene and use the alpha layer to do the masking. But I don't know how to use just the alpha in the VSE. Help?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15561/599

Comment: When linking video content you want to reproduce, skip to the part you want (copy the url at current time). Nobody has the time to watch a 13 minute video or skip through to find what you mean.

Comment: Its at the very beginning