# Want to make this Split and Slide Effect achieved in After Effects in the VSE

Tags: video-sequence-editor, keyframes, masking

I've been watching this tutorial on how to split your screen with a line that grows from nothing and bisects the screen. Letting you manipulate the two halves of the screen independently ; having one or the other move up and down, grow and colour change.

The tutorial is here:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oOZY7Yks6hI

[image]

He uses matte to determine the alpha channels of the two halves of the screen. He then parents the alpha channel to the matte.

I was hoping to do this process entirely in the VSE, however I don't know if theres the equivalent of the pen tool in Blender that AE has. 
I think I could use masks to achieve this but 1. I don't know how to make or use masks in the VSE 2. I don't know if it'll produce the desired result.

Any help would really appreciated!

Comment: I'd be doing this in Blender's 3D window, using planes textured with the same video, each distorted, split, treated as you wish, mostly straight forward and hassle free.  Your imagination would be pretty much the only limit when it comes to the effects you can achieve.

Comment: could you go into some more detail on how you would texture the planes to the video or image? Could i just use ordinary planes or would i have to modify them in some way for it to work? Cheers for all the help with my questions man!

Comment: Also some pictures or GIFS on how to do it would be extremely helpful as i find it hard to understand what you mean from reading text alone, images or videos would be easier to follow along in all honesty. If my question is too vague could you point me to similar questions with answers that i can use to piece together my own answer? CHEERS

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15561/animating-the-merging-of-multiple-video-strips

Comment: No, just ordinary ol' 2D planes used as 'screens' to show the same video on each.  You can delay one by a frame or two to give a ripple effect if desired.  I'm flat chat at the moment and will get back to you, but if you're looking for short examples via video, possibly for several aspects of your project in the future, we'd have to devise an easier and less time consuming method with which to converse.  Gif animation is quite easy and there are some posts in here on how to do this.  I can make a small video if you can't manage it.

Comment: Have done a video of some 5 simple (and rough) examples of animated split screens in Blender.  The gif files are all  too large to upload here so I've rendered them to one mp4. file.  If you create an anonymous email account I can upload the videos to that along with their Blend files if you want to see how they're done.  A hookup on say TeamView is probably a better way.

Comment: If you're still stuck with the split screens question, I've done a few Blender files which will show you how.  Leave a comment here if you need them...

Comment: This can be done in the vse as well. In the uv image editor define a mask and animate its appearance. Now add your strip in the vse and go to properties (n key) add a modifier 》mask. Then choose your animated mask. With the strip selected add an effect strip 》transform and set its blend type to Alpha Over. You should be able to move the masked video anywhere on screen

Comment: A comment on the planes in 3d view - remember to enable the 'Import Images as Planes' addon that ships with Blender, and they will come in with little fuss at the scale they need to be respecting the pixels and aspect ratio.

Answer (score 1):

Splitting screens:

[image]  [image]

The method I've used here is using the same principle for both.  A 2D plane for each video, one laid just above the other and the camera looking straight down.

Note:  Both are rendered using OpenGL, not Blender's internal render.

With the split screen an 'inviso mask' face was added to the lower edge of the white line. (thin rectangular plane laid just above the  video planes)  The line was simply rotated.

(inviso mask - plane with transparency set to 0.008)

In the torn or jaggy edge version, a single plane was used and textured with it's video.  A jagged edge (vertices) was cut into that using the knife function.  That was then duplicated (SHIFT-D) and dropped a little under the first

At the opening frame, only the top plane and video can be seen until reaching the frame where shape keys INSTANTANEOUSLY fold the respective outer edges of each plane downward and underneath. (hinged at the jagged edge)

In this example the left side of the top plane, and right side of the lower plane are folded down at the exact same frame that we start to rotate (tear) both planes out from the bottom center. (origin point set to the cursor which is already set to bottom center)

Twisting the planes in the Z axis on the way down can enhance the effect.

Underneath both planes a 3rd can be added as shown here textured with our favorite movie studio pattern.

Both Blend files are attached and compressed. VE5 (the 2nd) the straight out split screen, VE4 (1st) the torn screen.

If as you mentioned, you're still needing video footage as to how it was done that can be organised.  (hasn't been done yet)

The Blender files: (You'll need to substitute the original videos with your own)

Note:  Rendering used OpenGL, not Blender's internal render.

[image]

[image]

Thanks also to @3pointedit.  That could be another solution for you to try.

Comment: cheers for the answer, i think it answers my question but before I select my answer could you tell me why that now that i'm looking at your linked blend file that all the objects are pink? Cheers.

Comment: Yes, the movie files aren't there, you have to substitute them with your own (texturing panel) for each plane.

Comment: ah ok, that makes sense! I'll have a go now, cheers!

Comment: would i do that in the material or texture panel? Still not sure what the difference is really

Comment: Select one of the planes, click on the material panel, (for safety) then the texturing panel  go down to the image tab, open that, click on the upper folder and choose your own folder and image.

Comment: PS: when you select each plane, goto edit mode, set it's mode to FACES. (CTL-TAB)